# String formatting unsupported operand

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple program that prints the day month and year in mm/dd/yy form but I keep getting a trace-back error:

```
%s/%s/%s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/timenow.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('%s/%s/%s')%(now.month, now.day, now.year)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

I'm using python 3.4.0

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print('%s/%s/%s')%(now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to place the `%` operator just after the format string:

```
print('%s/%s/%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year))
```

Your current code has Python trying to use it on the `None` object returned by `print`:

```
>>> type(print('hi'))
hi
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

---

Also, I would like to mention two things.  The first is that the modern approach for string formatting is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) rather than the `%` operator:

```
print('{}/{}/{}'.format(now.month, now.day, now.year))
```

The second is that string formatting is not strictly needed here because we have the `print` function's [`sep` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), which is used to separate the arguments given to `print` by a certain string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> print(now.month, now.day, now.year, sep='/')
5/20/2014
>>>
```